# Is there an information theory for continuous time signals?

Tags: stochastic-processes, information-theory

Information theory books talk about entropy and mutual information of discrete time processes, such as a sequence of symbols sent with a symbol period $T_s$ and there received sequence.

Can we talk about the mutual information between two continuous time stochastic processes $X(t)$ and  $Y(t)$ in a way similar to the mutual information between two random variables $X$ and $Y$?

I guess the problem is the quantities in information theory are defined in densities of random variables. So can we define an instantaneous mutual information $I(X(t);Y(t))$ for the two processes at time $t$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can define it in the obvious way:
$$
\mathcal{I}(t) = \mathcal{I}[X_t,Y_t]=\iint p(x_t,y_t)\log\left[ 
\frac{p(x_t,y_t)}{p(x_t)p(y_t)} \right]\,dx_t\,dy_t
$$
This gives a time-varying mutual information signal, which is also a continuous function of time. 
For $t$ fixed, $\mathcal{I}(t)$ measures the (instantaneous) MI between the random variables $X_t$ and $Y_t$. 
The main challenge in practice is probably getting a high quality estimate of $p(x_t,y_t)$, i.e., how much data is needed for that.

One example I found is looking at Tostevin and ten Wolde, *Mutual information in time-varying biochemical systems*. The idea is to look at information transmission due to signal cascades in biochemistry, which are very noisy processes.